# Write out a specific cell from a 2 dimensional array in php (included from .csv)

Tags: php, arrays, csv, echo, multidimensional-array

here is my code. I really want to echo a specific cell from my CSV file without any MySQL stuff..

```
if (($handle = fopen("ebbe.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    # Set the parent multidimensional array key to 0.
    $nn = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        # Count the total keys in the row.
        $c = count($data);
        # Populate the multidimensional array.
        for ($x=0;$x<$c;$x++)
        {
            $csvarray[$nn][$x] = $data[$x];
            //echo $data[$x] . '<br>';
        }
        $nn++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The data is in the $csvarray multidimensional array, but i can't write out a specific one.
I tried this, but it said undefined offset on 2.

```
echo $csvarray[1][2];
```

Please help me! (yes, im a php noob :( )

Comment: How does your CSV look like?

Comment: It's a 2d array but the data you are storing is jus 1d

Comment: Run a `print_r($csvarray)` and see if it is what you are expecting.

Comment: You need to have something like '$data[][]'

Comment: The very least `$data[$nn] = array()` outside of the forloop.

Comment: Where is `$csvarray` defined and is it populated with anything before the for loop?

Comment: Do you want to echo from `$data` or add array data from `$data` to `$csvarray[0]` and then go from there?

Comment: you should define csvarray before you enter the loop. `$csvarray = array();` after that the entire contents of you loop can be replaced with `$csvarray[] = $data;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($csvarray);
 echo '</pre>';
```

It's gonna display contents of the array. Now that you have a visual presentation of your array, you should be able to see how much deeper you need to go.

Comment: Thanks, it seems better now. :)